# What do "except" and "idColumn" refers in "unique:table,column,except,idColumn"? from Laravel docs

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-5, validationrules

To validate the update of the e-mail of a user already registered I have the next function to exclude the "unique" rule for the current User:

```
public function updateRules() {
    return [
        'name'  => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|unique:users,email,'.$this->id,
    ];
}
```

In the Laravel docs https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#rule-unique I found the syntax `unique:table,column,except,idColumn` with 4 parameters:

- table: refers to the table name "users"
- column: refers the column name "email"
- except: I'm taking it as the id of the Model instance I want to exclude from the "unique" verification
- idColumn: I have no idea about this

Someone could clarify what do except and idColumn refers to?

**Note for those obsessed with duplicate questions**: I'm not asking how to do the rule exclusion for the update, because it seems to work just fine, I've read those questions and answers. I'm making helper functions and I need to know exactly what those two parameters means.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So you are right about the `except` parameter, it is the id that you want to be excluded from the check.

And `idColumn` is optional in case your column is not called `id` but `user_id` for example. So you will use:

```
'required|unique:users,email,'.$this->id . ',user_id';
```